# JAR is added as .ejb-client in EAR Module assembly RAD 8

Tags: rad, ejb-2.x

I am using Rational Application Developer v8.0.4 on Windows XP.

I have one ejb application A. I am trying to add the application A to the EAR Module Assembly of the application B ( This would create b.ear which contains A.jar as client EJB JAR). But the problem is that I try to add the project B as
 Right-Click on B --> Click on Properties --> Click On Deployment Assembly --> EAR Module Assembly section --> Click on Add --> Select Project --> Select Project B.

By doing this project B is added to Project A as B.ejb-client instead of B.jar. Can any one help me why is it so?